# How do I pass a NSString from a UITableViewController to another when the second one is embedded in a navigationcontroller?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller

I am encountering an issue when I want to pass a NSString in a Segue from a UITableViewController to another when the second UITableViewController is embedded in a navigationController, I am getting the following error message

```
UINavigationController setShopifyCollectionTitle:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1028b9200
2017-10-18 23:24:35.198874+0800 NWMobileTill[7364:3881864] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UINavigationController setShopifyCollectionTitle:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1028b9200'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x18979afe0 0x1881fc538 0x1897a1ef4 0x18979ef54 0x18969ad4c 0x100157cf8 0x19009559c 0x190095408 0x1900956d8 0x18f9f7a54 0x18faa7820 0x18fb59594 0x18fb4b630 0x18f8bf28c 0x1897489a8 0x189746630 0x189746a7c 0x189676da4 0x18b0e1074 0x18f931c9c 0x10015586c 0x18868559c)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

I assume the issue is that the navigationController is the destination in the segue as below

```
destViewController.shopifyCollectionTitle = selectedCollectionTitle;
```

the navigationController don't know that NSString it is the embedded UITableViewController that knows that NSString "shopifyCollectionTitle"

What do I need to do to pass that string "through" the naviationController to my UITableViewController?

NOTE: If I make the segue from the first UITableViewController to the second one directly by ctrl dragging directly to it then it works but then I don't get the navigation items etc, so the problem only occurs when I ctrl drag from the cell in the first Controller to the navigationController which has my UITableViewCOntroller embedded

How Can I make this work?

Comment: `destViewController` is a `UINavigationViewController`. So `destViewController.topViewController.shopifyCollectionTitle = selectedCollectionTitle;` You may have to cast before: `UINavigationViewController *navVC = (UINavigationViewController  *)segue.destinationViewController. MyCustomVC *vc = (MyCustomVC  *)navVC.topViewController. vc.shopifyCollectionTitle = selectedCollectionTitle;`

Comment: There is no topViewController option for me

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationcontroller/1621849-topviewcontroller ?

Comment: what I mean is I cannot type destViewController.topViewController.shopifyCollectionTitle there is no topViewController there

Comment: And did you read the whole comment? The part with "You may have to cast before:" ? In one line: `[(UINavigationController *)destViewController topViewController].shopifyCollectionTitle = ...;`?

Comment: I did and I cant get it to work still I get syntax error on the casting probably because the naming are wrong and I don't fully understand that casting line

Comment: I figured it out, you wrote UINavigationViewController in your first comment but its UINavigationController, works like a charm now thanks

Comment: Have you tried it with by creating a property in secondVC of NSString type then intantiateViewController _withIdentifier :Second VCidentifier then pass data to that screen and then use method self.view pushViewController:aboveCreatedObjectOfSecondVC animted:true